# Meaning of "das Gethane"

Tags: meaning

I don't find this word in any dictionary. What does it mean?

Sample excerpt, from [here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=AcAuMqmhfQkC&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=%22das%20Gethane%22&source=bl&ots=WlIKpXOkE2&sig=A4kVtcV9yjPZh9du75FYpO0W39A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6mf2sg57YAhWLKVAKHSKhDEQQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22das%20Gethane%22&f=false) :

> Der Akteur "erkennt das Gethane nur als das Seinige, insofern sich
>   darin die Bestimmung des Zweckes findet, die subjectiv in ihm war.
>   [...] In dem Meinigen verlange ich mein subjectives Wollen zu
>   erkennen; und nur in sofern dies darin erkenntlich, erkenne ich das
>   Gethane als das Meinige".

Comment: Your link points to outside the preview!

Comment: @Ludi: Click again! It seemed so to me too, but just by clicking a second time it worked. Must be a bug in google books.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This text is about 200 years old, it was written by Georg Wilhelm Friedrich Hegel (1770 - 1831).

Before the orthographic reform of 1901 the word *tun* (*to do*) was written with an h after t (*thun*). So also *das Getane* (*the done = what was done*) was written with this h.

So the first words of this paragraph translate to:

> The actor "recognizes *what was done* only as what is his, ...

Note, that the h after t in German was a marker for aspirated pronunciation of the t (i.e. short sound of breath after t).

Comment: And here is an example of a beautiful text from the end of that period. I took care not to choose a very old one, so that learners can guess the correspondences *Thal/Tal, That/Tat...* http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/brigitta-198/3

Comment: Well there was no standardised orthography until the 1870’s anyway …